# undefined variable in php listbox

Tags: undefined

Getting error on line 23 undefined variable $alltext when trying to populate fields from a listbox.  Have checked the database rows and they match up. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';

$sql = "SELECT supplierID,suppliername,street,town,county,telephone,balance FROM Suppliers";

if(!$result = mysql_query($sql, $con))
    {
    die("Error in querying the database".mysql_error());
    }

echo "<br><select name = 'listbox' id='listbox' onclick ='populate()'>" ;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['supplierID'];
    $name = $row['suppliername'];
    $street = $row['street'];
    $town = $row['town'];
    $county = $row['county'];
    $telephone = $row['telephone'];
    $balance = $row['balance'];
    $allText ="$id,$name,$street,$town,$county,$telephone,$balance";
    echo "<option value = '$alltext'>$name</option>";//<- undefined variable
}

echo "</select>";
mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: Please specify your environment and what you have tried. What did the debugger say?

Comment: solved it thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is incorrect. Change `$alltext` to `$allText`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the case on your variable names you have $allText and $alltext listed here.

Regards